# Size of a single \mathbf character

Tags: math-mode

Is there a way to increase the size of a single `\mathbf` character such as in `\mathbf{R}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you be more specific about your needs? In what context would you use this oversized character?

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
$x+ \mbox{\huge$\mathbb{R}$} + y$
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify the size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
$f + \scaleto{\mathbf{y}}{50pt} = z$
\end{document}
```